# Django- user posting Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

i am finding a problem in saving the user posts from my Django site. Whenever I try to run the submit form, it shows that the form has been submitted but I cant see the post being saved in the data base.

```
def addPost(request):
    form = hacksform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = hacksform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                newpost = form(commit= False)
                image = request.FILES['photo']
                newpost.author = request.user
                newpost.post_image = image
                newpost.save()
                newpost.save_m2m()
            except:
                newposts = form(commit=False)
                newpost.author = request.user
                newposts.save()
                newposts.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tweaks/tweaks')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/tweaks/tweaks')
```

and here is my forms.py file

```
class hacksform(forms.ModelForm):
    VIEW_CHOICES = (
    ("Option", "Choose Option"),
    ("Public", "To Public"),
    ("Channels", "To Channels"),
    )
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'user-title', 'placeholder': 'Title'}) ,required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'user-text', 'placeholder': 'Questions'}) ,required=False)
    tags = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-tag', 'placeholder': 'Add Tag'}) ,required=False)
    audience_privacy = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=VIEW_CHOICES,attrs={'id': 'selector'}) ,required=False)
    class Meta: 
        model = hacks
        fields = [
            'title',
            'author',
            'tags',
            'content',
            'post_image',
            'audience_privacy'
        ]
```

any ideas why I cant post

Answer (score 0):

```
def addPost(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = hacksform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            newpost = form(commit= False)
            image = request.FILES['photo']
            newpost.author = request.user
            newpost.post_image = image
            newpost.save()
            newpost.save_m2m()
        except:
            newposts = form(commit=False)
            newpost.author = request.user
            newposts.save()
            newposts.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tweaks/tweaks')
    else:
        print("errors",form.errors) # Print the errors on console
return HttpResponseRedirect('/tweaks/tweaks')
```